# How to pass a multidimensional array to a function without inner dimension in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there was a way to say pass this for example `double MyArray[][2] = {{0.1,0.8},{0.4,0.6}}` to a function like this `void MyFunction(double myArray[][]);`, without saying this `void MyFunction(double myArray[][2]);`. I need this because I want my function to be able to handle arrays with different inner dimensions for example: `double MyArray[][3] = {{0.1,0.8},{0.4,0.6},{0.3,0.9}}`. To pass this to a function as far as I know I would have to change MyFunctions's parameters to `MyFunction(myArray[][3]);`. From what I have read I don't know if this is possible, so if it is not then is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Is it an option to use a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` ?

Comment: Anything that can make this work the way I want it to is an option. So I think so.

Comment: In C++ templates are the answer.  Without templates you could just pass `double ** MyArray` but then you need to be careful because the function won't know how big the array is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an arbitrary 2d array by reference if you could change `MyFunction` to:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void MyFunction(double (&myArray)[N][M]) {
  // ...
}
```

This way you would also have dimensions of the array.

Comment: Can you have more than one template?

Comment: @MrQandA In what context?

Comment: I would like to have two arrays in MyFunction. How would I do this? `void MyFunction(double (&W)[N][M],double (&TD)[N][M])`?

Comment: @MrQandA sure you can you. You can also define more template parameters so that the the two can be of arbitrary dimension as well (e.g., `template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t M1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t M2>
void MyFunction(double (&myArray1)[N1][M1], double (&myArray2)[N2][M2]`)

Comment: How would you convert N1 to an integer?

Comment: @MrQandA `N1` is already an integral value you can use freely in the body of the function. As I said, the bonus is that you get the dimensions for free. (e.g., `for(int i = 0; i < N1; ++i) {...}`)

Comment: That gives me an error?

Comment: @MrQandA No it shouldn't here's a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df9ce04495d50511).

Comment: My compiler is minGW and it is giving me an error saying "required from here"?

Comment: Nvm I did for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i) {...}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with templates:

```
template < size_t Dim >
void fun(double (*array)[Dim], size_t outerDim);
```

At this point though I'd seriously consider using either `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has dynamic arrays, they are called [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can use vectors of vectors, e.g.

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double> > DMatrix;
```

and pass objects of this type around just as you would do it with any other object, i.e.

```
void foo(const DMatrix& matrix){
    for (int i=0;i<matrix.size();i++){
        for (int j=0;j<matrix.size();j++){
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusually common question.

Unfortunately, for straight arrays, you should do it the hard way.

First, you'll need a function to *index* an element of your mutli-dimensional array given the proper indices and dimensions. For a 2D array:

```
std::size_t index( std::size_t columns, std::size_t row, std::size_t column )
{
  return (row * columns) + column;
}
```

Note the lack of bounds-checking. You can add that if you like, but you should write code that doesn't need it. (Your function shouldn't need it, and the inline helper function will help your users not need it.)

Next, your function must work as in C -- taking an address of a *flattened* (one-dimensional) array and the dimensions. For example, here we'll print a const 2D array:

```
template <typename T>
void my_fn( const T* a, std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns )
{
  for (std::size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
  {
    for (std::size_t c = 0; c < columns; c++)
    {
      std::cout << a[ index( columns, r, c ) ] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Finally, you'll want to make some inline functions that translate into a call to your general-purpose function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
inline
void my_fn( const T (&a)[M][N] )
{
  return my_fn( (const T*)a, M, N );
}
```

Now you can use it with any 2D array:

```
int main()
{
  int xs[5][3];
  my_fn( xs );

  double ys[12][7];
  my_fn( ys );
```

Efficiency considerations:

- Code for the templated function should only be generated *once* for each *type;* different dimensions of the same type will all use that same function.
- The inline thunks should disappear completely -- optimized away by the compiler.
- Addressing elements is no more complicated than it would be otherwise, and should be automagically optimized the same.

Hope this helps.